# error in xcode 6 "is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist"

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

Trying to configure facebook connect in my app. newbie to xcode.

I should mention that i am using React-native.

I checked the configs 10 times

[image: plist screenshot]

still getting this error:

```
Exception thrown while invoking newSession on target <FacebookLoginManager: 0x7c2579d0> with params (
    5
): fb1413783292275789 is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist
```

React-native code :

```
    var FacebookLoginManager = require('NativeModules').FacebookLoginManager;
login() {
    FacebookLoginManager.newSession((error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        this.setState({result: error});
      } else {
        this.setState({result: info});
      }
    });
  }
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.login}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Facebook Login
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {this.state.result}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution is

Replace `URL types -> CFBundleURLTypes,  URL Schemes -> CFBundleURLSchemes`

even though it changes back automatically.
hit the play button and that’s it